# How to create a pneumatic wheel sound?

Tags: sound-effects, design, foley

I have to create the sound of a pneumatic wheel.

In the video there is a pneumatic that goes on the road for 15 sec. It starts with a road in the summer time and it turns in a winter road with snow.

How do I create the sound of a pneumatic wheel?

Comment: just for clarification: what is a pneumatic wheel exactly, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: sorry, googled the wheel. i would just try any type of tire in your library that rolls without engine sounds. or record it ofcourse! you can try to fake the snow sound.. 

Answer (score 3):

Record a wheelbarrow with well-lubed bearings on the surfaces you need: No motor noise, true pneumatic wheel. I can't count how many effects I've generated with wheelbarrows..!

Answer (score 1):

WHEELBARROW!!

Also, try different amounts of weights in the barrow, and try to lessen the air as well.